# Place \frontmatter chapter titles in the same place as \mainmatter chapter titles

Tags: chapters, titlesec, books

I desire that the word **Introduction** be precisely as far down from the top of page 1 as the words **Title of first chapter** are from the top of page 3.

I am using `\frontmatter` because I desire that the chapter titled **Introduction** be unnumbered.

Perhaps I could make use of `\phantom` to achieve this. But I do not know how.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=4.25in, paperheight=5.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\fillast}
{\Huge \thechapter}
{1ex minus .1ex}
{\large \thispagestyle{empty}}
{}

\titlespacing{\chapter}
{3pc}{*3}{*2}[3pc]

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[66]

\mainmatter
\chapter{Title of first chapter}
\lipsum[66]

\end{document}
```